# can't ssh login without password through nfs

Tags: linux, ssh, nfs

I have 3 nodes with centos 7 :master,slave01,slave02. i am trying to use ssh login without password among them, I've configured nfs filesystem among them, the master is server, the others are clients.
This is my installation steps of nfs:
on master node:

```
yum install nfs-utils
vi /etc/exports
```

In exports file, I add this line

```
/home/hadoop/.ssh *(sync,rw,no_boot_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=0)
```

then start nfs:

```
service rpcbind start
service nfs start
```

on client node:

```
yum install nfs-utils
service rpcbind start
mkdir /home/hadoop/nfs_share
mount -t nfs master:/ /home/hadoop/nfs_share
```

I'm sure nfs is ok. then I change to hadoop user to configue ssh without password.

on master node:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

on client node:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ln -s  /home/hadoop/nfs_share/authorized_keys /home/hadoop/.ssh/
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

that's all, but I can only ssh login master without password, when login slave, it still require to enter password. I've checked authority of /home they are 700 except authorized_keys,the authorized_keys is 644. following is the authorized_keys in my client:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 hadoop bigdata 1675 authorized_keys -> /home/hadoop/nfs_share/authorized_keys
```

later I run this command:

```
ssh slave01 -v
```

it prints some information may be useful:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

why did it happen?anyone could help me ,thanks in advance.

add1:

I've found this bug is most probably caused by nfs file system. when I modify the value of `AuthorizedKeysFile` in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`,
just change

```
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

to

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/hadoop/nfs_share/authorized_keys
```

It still didn't work. the /home/hadoop/nfs_share is my nfs system file,is located in my slave node. If I don't use the nfs system file ,it is ok. the file which is ok has the same owner ,group and permissions as the nfs system file.

Comment: In linux, there is a folder `/var/log` which has plenty of log files for all kinda stuff. Have a look into those: `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/ssh*`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Thanks, but I didn't find them. My system is centos 7, before there is a file named secure, but I delete it by accident

Comment: service rsyslog restart - then your log will re-appear. could be that ssh do not like authorized_keys file to be a symlink...